# how to animate 2 different html elements with jquery concurrently?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, move

I need to create a slide effect for 2 different html elements, but this animation must run concurrently.

is there a way with jquery.animate() function ?

Comment: Yes there is, but try explaining better what exactly it is your are trying to do, post some code or set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i have done complete bins which shows how can we animate two different HTML elements using jQuery. demo link as below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9a

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel1" class="edge">
  <div class="box" style="top:30; background:#f8a2a4;">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="panel2" class="edge">
  <div class="box" style="top:120; background:#5599fd;">
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Animate Block1" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Animate Block2" />
<input type="button" id="btn3" value="Animate Both" />
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
  background:#ffffef;
}
.edge{
  width:500px;
  height:70px;
  border:1px solid #3377af;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.box{
  position:absolute;
  left:10;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid #a82244;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        var move = "";
        if ($(".box", $("#panel1")).css('left') == "10px") {
            move = "+=" + ($("#panel1").width() - 35);
        } else {
            move = "-=" + ($("#panel1").width() - 35);
        }
        $(".box", $("#panel1")).animate({
            left: move
        }, 500, function() {
            if ($(this).css('left') == "475px") {
                $(this).css('background', '#afa799');
            } else {
                $(this).css('background', '#f8a2a4');
            }

        });
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        var move = "";
        if ($(".box", $("#panel2")).css('left') == "10px") {
            move = "+=" + ($("#panel2").width() - 35);
        } else {
            move = "-=" + ($("#panel2").width() - 35);
        }
        $(".box", $("#panel2")).animate({
            left: move
        }, 500, function() {
            if ($(this).css('left') == "475px") {
                $(this).css('background', '#afa799');
            } else {
                $(this).css('background', '#5599fd');
            }

        });
    });
    //Call Event Con-currently for both blocks
    $("#btn3").click(function() {
        $("#btn1").add("#btn2").click();
    });

});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9a

Answer (score 0):

I was simply trying to move a div and CONCURRENTLY move an IMG

I was forgetting that two .animate() one after other run automatically in concurrence.

sorry for time losing...